# Python create dictionary from json values

Tags: python, json

I currently do an API call to the Steam Web API which gets a json response which looks like this:

```
{
"response": {
    "globalstats": {
        "heist_success": {
            "total": "58932654920",
            "history": [
                {
                    "date": 1486252800,
                    "total": "696574"
                },
                {
                    "date": 1486339200,
                    "total": "357344"
                },
                {
                    "date": 1486425600,
                    "total": "356800"
                },
                {
                    "date": 1486512000,
                    "total": "311056"
                }
            ]

        }
    },
    "result": 1
}
```

The date is in unix time stamp and the total is an amount. What I want to do is create a dictionary from the values in date and time and not the names. I tried using the following:

```
dict = dict(data['response']['globalstats']['heist_success']['history'])
```

But that just created a dict of "date" "total".

How can I create a dict of just the values?

Comment: To clearify, I want to create a dict with the timestamp in the first column and the amount in the second one.

Comment: With the timestamp *as key* and the amount *as value*…?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may get the values and make dictionary out of it ,

This is what you may do

**Code**

```
d = data['response']['globalstats']['heist_success']['history']
result_dict = dict((i["date"],i["total"]) for i in d)
```

You may also use `dict comprehension` if using python version  **2.7** or above

```
result_dict = {i["date"]:i["total"]  for i in d}
```

**Output**

```
{1486252800: '696574',
 1486339200: '357344',
 1486425600: '356800',
 1486512000: '311056'}
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry but I can't since I got less than 15 rep myself :/

Comment: Didn't see that... Done!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
D = {h['date']:h['total'] for h in data['response']['globalstats']['heist_success']['history']}
```

The `for` will iterate over the list of dicts in history and date and total are selected as the key and value.